# Half circle with percentage in CSS

Tags: html, css, border, geometry

I am trying to create an half circle with CSS using border-radius with percentage but I have no ideas. Is there a method to do so?

Comment: Google css shapes. This exists already

Answer (score 0):

Try to style your **div** like this:

```
div{
 height:45px;
 width:90px;
 border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
 background:green; }
```

This creates a half green circle, hope that works for you.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answare.What I want to do is to create an half circle with border radius' values set in percentage

Comment: Play around with this https://codepen.io/xram/pen/thLsk Codepen snippet and change the pixels to percentage. And why do yo need the border radius to be in %?

Comment: Already done.If I set the border radius to: 100% 100% 0% 0%  i don't get the same result

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use percentages, if so the container needs to be fixed size and cutoff overflow.

If you have HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div class="pie"></div></div>
```

Then this CSS will work:

```
.container {
    height: 45px;
    width: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pie {
     height: 200%;
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
     background: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi:)This works only if I want a semi-circle on top.If I want a semi-circle on the left for example?I have to set a negative margin?